# Changing the DateTime format

Tags: angular, date-formatting

I am using the below code in order to get date and time from calender controller.

```
startdate: this.datePipe.transform(this.startDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'), enddate: this.datePipe.transform(this.endDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm') }])
```

The above code returns DateTime as : `2018-09-26T04:56:00.000Z`

How can I convert it in to the below format.

`2018-09-26 04:56:00.00`

Comment: What's `this.datePipe`? Does it give back Date objects? If so, you're probably just seeing the ISO representation of the date.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're printing the correct thing? What you see is ISO format. You're probably printing the `Date` object instead of the formatted string. Please post a full reproduction.

Comment: Try like this, this.datepipe.transform(this.startDateTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');

Answer (score 0):

Check out the npm package [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

It would involve something along these lines:

`moment(startdate, moment.ISO_8601).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Why would you load `moment` for a task which has a proper non-bloated solution in Angular?